# Scraping with beautifulsoup trying to get all the href attributes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape all the urls from amazon categories website (https://www.amazon.com/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn)

but I can just get the first url of any category. For example, from "Amazon video" I am getting "All videos", "Fire TV" amazon fire tv, etc.

That is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.amazon.es/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn"

amazon_link = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(amazon_link.text,"html.parser")

categorias_amazon = html.find_all('div',{'class':'popover-grouping'})

for i in range(len(categorias_amazon)):
   print("www.amazon.es" + categorias_amazon[i].a['href'])
```

I have tried with:

```
print("www.amazon.es" + categorias_amazon[i].find_all['a'])
```

but I get an error. I am looking to get `href` attribute of every sub category.

Comment: I can't find any elements that are contained within a `.popover-grouping`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.amazon.es/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn"

amazon_link = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(amazon_link.text,"html.parser")

# print html

categorias_amazon = html.find_all('div',{'class':'popover-grouping'})


allurls=html.select("div.popover-grouping [href]")

values=[link['href'].strip() for link in allurls]

for value in values:
   print("www.amazon.es" + value)
```

It will print:

```
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1748200031
www.amazon.es/gp/dmusic/mp3/player
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=2133385031
www.amazon.es/clouddrive/primephotos
www.amazon.es/clouddrive/home
www.amazon.es/clouddrive/home#download-section
www.amazon.es/clouddrive?_encoding=UTF8&sf=1
www.amazon.es/dp/B0186FET66
www.amazon.es/dp/B00QJDO0QC
www.amazon.es/dp/B00IOY524S
www.amazon.es/dp/B010EK1GOE
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=827234031
www.amazon.es/ebooks-kindle/b?ie=UTF8&node=827231031
www.amazon.es/gp/kindle/ku/sign-up/
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=8504981031
www.amazon.es/gp/digital/fiona/kcp-landing-page
www.amazon.eshttps://www.amazon.es:443/gp/redirect.html?location=https://leer.amazon.es/&token=CA091C61DBBA8A5C0F6E4A46ED30C059164DBC74&source=standards
www.amazon.es/gp/digital/fiona/manage
www.amazon.es/dp/B00ZDWLEEG
www.amazon.es/dp/B00IRKMZX0
www.amazon.es/dp/B01AHBC23E
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=827234031
www.amazon.es/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=1661649031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1726755031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1748200031
www.amazon.es/ebooks-kindle/b?ie=UTF8&node=827231031
www.amazon.es/gp/digital/fiona/manage
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10909716031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10909718031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10909719031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10909720031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10909721031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10909722031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=8464150031
www.amazon.es/mobile-apps/b?ie=UTF8&node=1661649031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1726755031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=4622953031
www.amazon.es/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000658923
www.amazon.es/gp/mas/your-account/myapps
www.amazon.es/comprar-libros-espa%C3%B1ol/b?ie=UTF8&node=599364031
www.amazon.es/ebooks-kindle/b?ie=UTF8&node=827231031
www.amazon.es/gp/kindle/ku/sign-up/
www.amazon.es/Libros-en-ingl%C3%A9s/b?ie=UTF8&node=665418031
www.amazon.es/Libros-en-otros-idiomas/b?ie=UTF8&node=599367031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=902621031
www.amazon.es/libros-texto/b?ie=UTF8&node=902673031
www.amazon.es/Blu-ray-DVD-peliculas-series-3D/b?ie=UTF8&node=599379031
www.amazon.es/series-tv-television-DVD-Blu-ray/b?ie=UTF8&node=665293031
www.amazon.es/Blu-ray-peliculas-series-3D/b?ie=UTF8&node=665303031
www.amazon.es/M%C3%BAsica/b?ie=UTF8&node=599373031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1748200031
www.amazon.es/musical-instruments/b?ie=UTF8&node=3628866031
www.amazon.es/fotografia-videocamaras/b?ie=UTF8&node=664660031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=931491031
www.amazon.es/tv-video-home-cinema/b?ie=UTF8&node=664659031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=664684031
www.amazon.es/gps-accesorios/b?ie=UTF8&node=664661031
www.amazon.es/musical-instruments/b?ie=UTF8&node=3628866031
www.amazon.es/accesorios/b?ie=UTF8&node=928455031
www.amazon.es/Inform%C3%A1tica/b?ie=UTF8&node=667049031
www.amazon.es/Electr%C3%B3nica/b?ie=UTF8&node=599370031
www.amazon.es/portatiles/b?ie=UTF8&node=938008031
www.amazon.es/tablets/b?ie=UTF8&node=938010031
www.amazon.es/ordenadores-sobremesa/b?ie=UTF8&node=937994031
www.amazon.es/componentes/b?ie=UTF8&node=937912031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=2457643031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=2457641031
www.amazon.es/Software/b?ie=UTF8&node=599376031
www.amazon.es/pc-videojuegos-accesorios-mac/b?ie=UTF8&node=665498031
www.amazon.es/Inform%C3%A1tica/b?ie=UTF8&node=667049031
www.amazon.es/material-oficina/b?ie=UTF8&node=4352791031
www.amazon.es/productos-papel-oficina/b?ie=UTF8&node=4352794031
www.amazon.es/boligrafos-lapices-utiles-escritura/b?ie=UTF8&node=4352788031
www.amazon.es/electronica-oficina/b?ie=UTF8&node=4352790031
www.amazon.es/oficina-papeleria/b?ie=UTF8&node=3628728031
www.amazon.es/videojuegos-accesorios-consolas/b?ie=UTF8&node=599382031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=665290031
www.amazon.es/pc-videojuegos-accesorios-mac/b?ie=UTF8&node=665498031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=8490963031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1381541031
www.amazon.es/Juguetes-y-juegos/b?ie=UTF8&node=599385031
www.amazon.es/bebe/b?ie=UTF8&node=1703495031
www.amazon.es/baby-reg/homepage
www.amazon.es/gp/family/signup
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=2181872031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=3365351031
www.amazon.es/bano/b?ie=UTF8&node=3244779031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=1354952031
www.amazon.es/iluminacion/b?ie=UTF8&node=3564289031
www.amazon.es/pequeno-electrodomestico/b?ie=UTF8&node=2165363031
www.amazon.es/aspiracion-limpieza-planchado/b?ie=UTF8&node=2165650031
www.amazon.es/almacenamiento-organizacion/b?ie=UTF8&node=3359926031
www.amazon.es/climatizacion-calefaccion/b?ie=UTF8&node=3605952031
www.amazon.es/Hogar/b?ie=UTF8&node=599391031
www.amazon.es/herramientas-electricas-mano/b?ie=UTF8&node=3049288031
www.amazon.es/Cortacespedes-Tractores-Jardineria/b?ie=UTF8&node=3249445031
www.amazon.es/instalacion-electrica/b?ie=UTF8&node=3049284031
www.amazon.es/accesorios-cocina-bano/b?ie=UTF8&node=3049286031
www.amazon.es/seguridad/b?ie=UTF8&node=3049292031
www.amazon.es/Bricolaje-Herramientas-Fontaneria-Ferreteria-Jardineria/b?ie=UTF8&node=2454133031
www.amazon.es/Categorias/b?ie=UTF8&node=6198073031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=6348071031
www.amazon.es/Categorias/b?ie=UTF8&node=6198055031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=12300685031
www.amazon.es/Salud-y-cuidado-personal/b?ie=UTF8&node=3677430031
www.amazon.es/Suscribete-Ahorra/b?ie=UTF8&node=9699700031
www.amazon.es/Amazon-Pantry/b?ie=UTF8&node=10547412031
www.amazon.es/moda-mujer/b?ie=UTF8&node=5517558031
www.amazon.es/moda-hombre/b?ie=UTF8&node=5517557031
www.amazon.es/moda-infantil/b?ie=UTF8&node=5518995031
www.amazon.es/bolsos-mujer/b?ie=UTF8&node=2007973031
www.amazon.es/joyeria/b?ie=UTF8&node=2454126031
www.amazon.es/relojes/b?ie=UTF8&node=599388031
www.amazon.es/equipaje/b?ie=UTF8&node=2454129031
www.amazon.es/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=12464607031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=8520792031
www.amazon.es/running/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928523031
www.amazon.es/fitness-ejercicio/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928495031
www.amazon.es/ciclismo/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928487031
www.amazon.es/tenis-padel/b?ie=UTF8&node=2985165031
www.amazon.es/golf/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928503031
www.amazon.es/deportes-equipo/b?ie=UTF8&node=2975183031
www.amazon.es/deportes-acuaticos/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928491031
www.amazon.es/deportes-invierno/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928493031
www.amazon.es/Tiendas-campa%C3%B1a-Sacos-dormir-Camping/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928471031
www.amazon.es/deportes-aire-libre/b?ie=UTF8&node=2454136031
www.amazon.es/ropa-calzado-deportivo/b?ie=UTF8&node=2975170031
www.amazon.es/calzado-deportivo/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928484031
www.amazon.es/electronica-dispositivos-el-deporte/b?ie=UTF8&node=2928496031
www.amazon.es/Coche-y-moto/b?ie=UTF8&node=1951051031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=2566955031
www.amazon.es/gps-accesorios/b?ie=UTF8&node=664661031
www.amazon.es/Motos-accesorios-piezas/b?ie=UTF8&node=2425161031
www.amazon.es/industrial-cientfica/b?ie=UTF8&node=5866088031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=6684191031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=6684193031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=6684192031
www.amazon.es/handmade/b?ie=UTF8&node=9699482031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10740508031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10740511031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10740559031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10740502031
www.amazon.es/b?ie=UTF8&node=10740505031
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to scrapp it or scrape it?  If it's the latter, that about this?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.amazon.es/gp/site-directory/ref=nav_shopall_btn")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```